# Return the average per group in each line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I have the following table `exampleTable` in my database:

| exampleGroup | exampleName | exampleValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | name1 | 100 |
| B | name2 | 500 |
| C | name3 | 300 |
| B | name4 | 700 |
| A | name5 | 500 |
| C | name6 | 600 |

My goal is to return the following result, where I have the average value per group in an additional column:

| exampleGroup | exampleName | exampleValue | averageExampleGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | name1 | 100 | 300 |
| A | name5 | 500 | 300 |
| B | name2 | 500 | 600 |
| B | name4 | 700 | 600 |
| C | name3 | 300 | 450 |
| C | name6 | 600 | 450 |

What I tried so far (with mistake, because it doesn't calculate the average per group but the total average value of all columns):

```
SELECT 
    exampleGroup, exampleName, exampleValue,
    (SELECT AVG(exampleValue) FROM exampleTable) AS averageExampleGroup
FROM exampleTable;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `OVER()` clause like this:

```
SELECT 
    exampleGroup, exampleName, exampleValue,
    AVG(exampleValue) OVER (PARTITION BY exampleGroup) AS GroupAvg
FROM exampleTable;
```

This returns the *average* based on each `exampleGroup` as a new column in your result set.

Answer (score 2):

Use over()

```
select exampleGroup, exampleName, exampleValue,
  Avg(exampleValue) over(partition by exampleGroup) averageExampleGroup
from exampleTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average per group, then you need to limit the rows to that particular group. In other words, you need to qualify the `SELECT AVG(...` with a `where`.

```sql
SELECT e1.exampleGroup
      ,e1.exampleName
      ,e1.exampleValue
      ,(SELECT AVG(e2.exampleValue)
          FROM exampleTable e2
         where e2.exampleGroup = e1.exampleGroup) AS averageExampleGroup
FROM exampleTable e1;
```